# Spring Security SecurityFilterChain not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot 3 project which has both web pages and an API. The REST API should be open (and use API keys) and the rest of the application will be authenticated. I have a separate filter which handles the key checking.

For example, if I do not supply an API key, and I use this security config, it does not return the correct JSON error and instead forward me to the login page.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint.class)).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/actuator/*").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/api/**");

    http.oauth2Login(withDefaults())
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", HttpMethod.GET.name()))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");

    return http.build();
}
```

Here is the debug:

```
2023-01-23T16:47:29.600  INFO 20700 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-01-23T16:47:29.600  INFO 20700 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-01-23T16:47:29.600 DEBUG 20700 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2023-01-23T16:47:29.600 DEBUG 20700 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2023-01-23T16:47:29.600 DEBUG 20700 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2023-01-23T16:47:29.601 DEBUG 20700 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@72c0080a
2023-01-23T16:47:29.601 DEBUG 20700 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@7586194b
2023-01-23T16:47:29.601 DEBUG 20700 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2023-01-23T16:47:29.601  INFO 20700 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-01-23T16:47:32.136 DEBUG 20700 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.imsweb.seertransfer.controller.ApiController#processImport()
2023-01-23T16:47:32.138 DEBUG 20700 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.imsweb.seertransfer.controller.ApiController#processImport()
2023-01-23T16:47:32.145 DEBUG 20700 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-01-23T16:47:32.147 DEBUG 20700 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
```

However if I switch the requestMatchers to "/**":

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint.class)).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/actuator/*").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/api/**");

    http.oauth2Login(withDefaults())
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", HttpMethod.GET.name()))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");

    return http.build();
}
```

I now get the correct results back:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-01-23T21:55:39.115Z",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "You must supply an access token",
    "path": "/api/import"
}
```

and the log looks different:

```
2023-01-23T16:48:47.791  INFO 10824 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-01-23T16:48:47.792  INFO 10824 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-01-23T16:48:47.792 DEBUG 10824 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2023-01-23T16:48:47.792 DEBUG 10824 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2023-01-23T16:48:47.792 DEBUG 10824 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2023-01-23T16:48:47.793 DEBUG 10824 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@1910b7
2023-01-23T16:48:47.793 DEBUG 10824 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@6ee194ac
2023-01-23T16:48:47.793 DEBUG 10824 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2023-01-23T16:48:47.793  INFO 10824 --- [2)-172.22.34.73] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-01-23T16:48:51.362 DEBUG 10824 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.imsweb.seertransfer.controller.ApiController#processImport()
2023-01-23T16:48:51.365 DEBUG 10824 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.imsweb.seertransfer.controller.ApiController#processImport()
2023-01-23T16:48:51.372 DEBUG 10824 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-01-23T16:48:51.374 DEBUG 10824 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}
2023-01-23T16:48:51.376 DEBUG 10824 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-01-23T16:48:51.388 DEBUG 10824 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2023-01-23T16:48:51.389 DEBUG 10824 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Mon Jan 23 16:48:51 EST 2023, status=401, error=Unauthorized, message=You must supply an  (truncated)...]
2023-01-23T16:48:51.399 DEBUG 10824 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 401
```

Is there something different that needs to be done with the matchers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I was having every endpoint be authenticated except "/api/**". The problem turned out that when there is an error, the call is forwarded to "/error" even though it is only going to return JSON.

My solution was to change

```
.requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
```

to

```
.requestMatchers("/api/**", "/error").permitAll()
```

Now the REST API is accessible and returns correct JSON errors, while the rest of the application is still authenticated. It seems strange to have to have the error page outside of auth, but it does work.

Answer (score 3):

Create two separate [`SecurityFilterChain`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/SecurityFilterChain.html) beans: one for REST configuration and one for the default configuration. Use `http.securityMatcher(...)` before `authorizeHttpRequests()` so that the REST filter chain only handles requests to API endpoints. In addition, ensure that the `/error` path is publicly accessible as it handles returning the JSON for errors.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults()).logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
            .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", HttpMethod.GET.name()))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/error").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain restSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.securityMatcher("/api/**", "/actuator/*").authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll().requestMatchers("/actuator/*")
            .hasAuthority("ADMIN").and().csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/api/**");
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: That fixes the "/api/**" endpoints which now return the JSON errors. However the rest of the application doesn't have authentication anymore.

Comment: @ChuckM Add the authentication on the first security filter chain, but remember to allow access to /error.

Comment: I wasn't able to get your code to work properly for me, but your comment on /error was the key. I posted a solution above where I just added "/error" to the permitAll and everything works now.

Comment: @ChuckM Happy to help. Note that in general, it's better to have a separate `SecurityFilterChain` configuration for your REST API so that you can have separate exception handling and/or authentication methods.

Comment: @ChuckM Also you should be able to get it to work by adding the following to the `securityFilterChain` Bean method: `http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/error").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();`

Comment: Yup, that works also. Is there any advantage of splitting this into two beans as opposed to how I did it above?

Comment: @ChuckM It's often better to have [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). For instance, you can configure Spring Security `exceptionHandling` or other parts of the security architecture differently. And although not exactly relevant here, you can have two separate sets of login pages with different SecurityFilterChains.

Comment: @ChuckM No problem. Good luck with the rest of your project!